# Shortest Path, but on a physical maze

Tags: algorithm

I'm implementing a robot to be able to solve any maze (where the robot only has front sensors, but I make it scan the surroundings), and I was able to get it to turn the maze into a map where 0 represents walls, and 1 represents roads, with possibly slanted roads. Now, the robot is not fast at turning, but fairly fast at moving down a straight line. Therefore, a normal shortest path algorithm through the somewhat slanted hallway would be slow, although the paths are wide enough for it.

For example, we find

```
0001111111000
0011111110000
0111111100000
1111111000000
1111110000000
```

As a possible map. I'd like the robot to recognize that it can walk diagonally, or even just go straight up then right then right again, instead of turning every time in a normal shortest path algorithm.

Any ideas? Also, a complete algorithm change is welcome too - I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: You get all the map at once?

Comment: Can you tell me the difference time between a straight move and a turn?
The shortest path here should calculate the minimum time reaching the goal?

Comment: you can use 2D grid map A* for this ... with different increase in cell value for turning and for movement. also can you align to wall or you can do just 90 degree turns? What is the robot width in cells... also this is fastest path not shortest

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar problem some time ago.

You can assign weights to surrounding cells and less weight to the front cell, thus making a weight graph that is made during the movement.
I used Dijkstra algorithm with weights of 2 for surrounding cells and weight 1 for the front cell, you must pass direction of robot to Dijkstra and when adding them to the priority queue, and when extracting cells from the queue add the neighbors with respect to the direction saved in the extracted cell.

Then make the move and then recompute the modified Dijkstra for finding the nearest unseen cell.